# building a site like padmapper

Tags: map

Is it a complicated process to build a site like padmapper.com?

I am interested in producing a regional equivalent for Australia.

Comment: The question of whether or not building a site is a complicated process is too general and subjective to meet the Pro Webmasters quality guidelines. Please review our [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) and inquire on [Meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if it is unclear why this question was closed.

Answer (score 0):

I really depends on your level of programming knowledge. Padmapper is build around the Google Maps API accessed with PHP. As someone who has been building website for a while now, I don't think a site like this would be super hard to do. (I'd personally use Django + Geo-Django for the backend).

But if you are a beginning programmer using this as a learning project, it would probably be a bit difficult to do since the Google API can be hard to understand for beginning programmers.

So is it complicated to do? No, if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [huge performance improvements](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/03/09/bing-maps-v-7-tops-the-ajax-performance-charts.aspx) in [Bing Maps AJAX map control version 7](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/), it is one more option that you can explore to [build a custom mapping app](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/licensing.aspx).